# Grace Note Web API not resolving

Tags: gracenote

I created a new app a week ago and am trying to access the soap API however using the endpoint address as specified in the documentation (https://developer.gracenote.com/sites/default/files/web/html/index.html#PDFs/Music Web API Release Notes (1.1)-o.pdf) will not resolve the URL.

I am connecting to the end point https://cxxxxxxxx.web.cddb.net/webapi/xml/1.0 (I am replacing the xxxxxxxx with my client id)

If I run an nslookup off cxxxxxxxx.web.cddb.net from Googles public servers 8.8.8.8 I get non-existent domain.  (Again I am replacing the xxxxxxxx with my client id)

Does the free license not work for the web API?

Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing one letter! From the documentation on https://developer.gracenote.com/web-api, the correct endpoint should be:

https://cXXXXXXX.web.cddbp.net/webapi/xml/1.0/

Notice the "p" at the end of the "cddb".

Also, make sure that you replace the XXXXXX's with only the digits that precede the hyphen in your Client ID string. i.e. if your Client ID string is "1234567-09876543210987654321" (not a real Client ID), then you would send requests to https://c1234567.web.cddbp.net/webapi/xml/1.0/

Comment: Wow I'm an idiot sometimes it just takes an extra set of eyes.  Thank you that was the issue I was missing the 'p'.  End point resolves now.